# How to pass thousands of records to thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have retrieved thousands of record from db into `ArrayList`. 
And I need to form report based on this records.

How do apply multi thread to achive this functionality in Java.

Comment: What language are you using? What is your current code? I'd expect someone with 3 years of SO experience to know what is expected from a question.

Comment: He's using java (now amended the question)

Comment: Please edit your question to show your work.  What have you tried?  Any code samples? This question is very vague otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the specifics of what you're trying, I would point you to the [Executor tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html).

Using the Executor framework allows you to split your work into jobs (Callables) and the executor will look after executing these jobs in parallel (using pooling etc.). You simply have to query/wait on your jobs to complete without having to handle the complexities of `notify()`/`wait()`/`join()` etc.

The API abstracts out the pooling/thread creation concerns plus the scheduling and determining when your jobs are complete (and/or exception handling)

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide more details, but in general *Producer-Consumer* pattern should work. Try with something simple like [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html):

```
final List<Record> records = //...
final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
for (final Record record : records) {
    executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //process record here
        }
    });
}
```

This code will take each record and process it in parallel in up to 10 threads. Of course it depends on your requirements what you want to do with that. E.g. use [`Callable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) to return some result, [`ExecutorCompletionService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) to wait for first result, etc.